# Pyspark power all dataframe except one column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe which looks like this one:

```
Id   a1  a2  a3   
+--+---+---+---+
1  |5  |45 |4
2  |2  |12 |79
3  |7  |8  |56
```

I would like to create new dataframe, which would power all columns by value m, except id column. This is what i have so far:

```
  dfCluster = U.select(* ( ( pow(col(c),m )).alias(c) for c in U.columns))
```

but this code powers all columns, including 'Id' column. I tried this code as well:

```
dfCluster = U.select(* ( ( pow(col(c),m )).alias(c) for c in U.columns if c not in 'ColumnIndex'))
```

but then in the new dataframe I don't get 'Id' column at all, **but i need it**. Any ideas how to power all table except 'Id' column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple generator expression, leaving `Id` outside:

```
U.select('Id', *(pow(U[col], m).alias(col) for col in U.columns if col != 'Id'))
```